# How to understand Bluemix accounts and billing management

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to understand how to manage accounts on Bluemix. Say as part of my company teams, I want to have one account with Bluemix for each team and get the billing for that account, how do I do it? I could not locate any documentation on that.

Can someone point me to the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluemix allows you to organise your work and activities through Organisations and spaces, which are the real owners of the apps and services running inside, and the entities which are interested by pay per usage Bluemix pricing.

Inside an org and its spaces you could invite users and then you could give them different roles manager/auditor/developer according to the permissions you would like to grant them

Each space then is a sandbox for applications and services without any visibility with other ones

Then the main org will be billed according to platform usage following what is described here

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/pricing/

So to answer your question, you could simply have one org and the manage the users invited into according to your need.
Obviously nothing will prevent you from creating more organisation to have more granularity

An important note: users to be invited don't need to be registered on Bluemix in advance: they will create their IBM ID (if not owning one yet) once accessing Bluemix for the first time

You could find further information following the Bluemix documentation

Comment: So well elaborated. Thanks. In the mean time I also could reach this page that talks about and elaborates these. https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/index.html#orgsandspaces

Comment: Correct. This page provides a great tutorial for users/groups management.